# This feature is not currently enabled either for this record type or the given user type or org

Tags: community, knowledge, articles, topics

I am setting up a Salesforce Community. I'm currently defining Topics and trying to associate topics with Articles, but when I try to do this, I get the following error:

> This feature is not currently enabled either for this record type or
>   the given user type or org

This search comes up empty on Google. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here's what the error looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> This is because for your Article Type object the Topics are disabled .Please follow below screeshots to enable it.

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

Click on Enable Topics and you should be good .I reproduced your issue in my instance and this seemed to work fine once I enabled Topics for knowledge article type .

Comment: 2 things to note here. 1 it is only available in salesforce classic. 2. you need to enable it for Knowledge if you are dealing with articles.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having issues with this. I was following along with the link posted (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247452&type=1) and noticed I had to switch to classic to enable the topics - don't forget this important step!

Answer (score 0):

Adding help article for as source of Mohith's comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247452&type=1